# No Ripple Effect With SelectableItemBackground

Tags: android, material-design

I'm trying to implement material design to legacy code.

I want a button to have a ripple effect on click but it shows nothing.

I'm using default `?android:attr/selectableItemBackground`.

this is button xml:

```
<Button
                android:text="Wandio"
                android:padding="10dp"
                android:textColor="#ffffff"
                android:background="?android:attr/selectableItemBackground"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:id="@+id/wandio_link" />
```

style in `values` folder:

```
<resources>
    <color name="main_green">#45bb61</color>
    <style name="AppTheme" parent="AppTheme.Base">
    </style>
    <style name="Theme.Splash" parent="android:Theme">
        <item name="android:windowNoTitle">true</item>
        <item name="windowActionBar">false</item>
    </style>
    <style name="AppTheme.Base" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
        <item name="windowNoTitle">true</item>
        <item name="windowActionBar">false</item>
        <item name="colorPrimary">#909CD4</item>
        <item name="colorPrimaryDark">#D490CA</item>
        <item name="colorAccent">#FFFFFF</item>
        <item name="android:imageButtonStyle">@style/ImageButtonStyle</item>
        <item name="android:windowBackground">@color/main_green</item>
    </style>
  <style name="ImageButtonStyle">
    <item name="android:background">@android:color/transparent</item>
  </style>
</resources>
```

style in `values-v21` folder:

```
<resources>
<style name="AppTheme" parent="AppTheme.Base">
    <item name="windowNoTitle">true</item>
    <item name="windowActionBar">false</item>
    <item name="android:windowContentTransitions">true</item>
    <item name="android:windowAllowEnterTransitionOverlap">true</item>
    <item name="android:windowAllowReturnTransitionOverlap">true</item>
    <item name="android:windowSharedElementEnterTransition">@android:transition/move</item>
    <item name="android:windowSharedElementExitTransition">@android:transition/move</item>
    <item name="android:windowTranslucentStatus">true</item>
    <item name="android:fitsSystemWindows">true</item>
    <item name="android:imageButtonStyle">@style/StyleApi21</item>
    <item name="android:buttonStyle">@style/StyleApi21</item>
</style>
<style name="StyleApi21">
         <item name="android:background">?android:attr/selectableItemBackgroundBorderless</item>
</style>
```

Never had this problem before. Can't find what I'm missing. 
Any suggestions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I tryed the same thing and I have used this in my custom button xml:

```
<item ><ripple xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:color="?android:colorControlHighlight">
        <item android:id="@android:id/mask">
            <shape android:shape="oval">
                <solid android:color="#FFBB00" />
            </shape>
        </item>
        <item>
            <shape android:shape="oval">
                <solid android:color="@color/colorAccent" />

            </shape>
        </item>
    </ripple>
```

Here is my another xml for older devices:

```
<item>
        <selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

            <item android:drawable="@drawable/fab_selected" android:state_selected="true"/>
            <item android:drawable="@drawable/fab_pressed" android:state_pressed="true"/>
            <item android:drawable="@drawable/fab_normal"/>

        </selector>
    </item>
```

These drawable files are just different colors of the button.

Comment: should I add another drawable for pre-lollipop devices or will this be enough?

Comment: Yes I added one drawable for v21 and one for the older devices.

Comment: Can you post another xml for older devices?